# With statement with two variables

Tags: python, django

How would I combine a `with` with a `firstof` in the django template? For example:

```
{% firstof item.item.master_id item.tracktitle.master_id %}
{% with ^^ above as master_id %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) for `firstof` explains how to do this:

> You can use the syntax `{% firstof var1 var2 var3 as value %}` to store the output inside a variable.

Which you can then use as:

```
{% with value as master_id %}
```